# How to decide which forecasting model to use?

Tags: predictive-modeling, prediction, forecasting

So I have a **sales forecasting problem** where I have 3 years worth of data about weekly sales of a certain company.

There are 3 types of retail stores in that company, Type A, B, and C. There are a total of 45 stores which fall in either of the 3 category. There are a total of 99 departments under each store, but not all stores have all the 99 departments.

I also know which weeks were holiday weeks. I also have the average temperature, average fuel prices, average unemployment rate and the average consumer price index for each week of the region where a particular store is located. I also have the size of each store. Add to it I have the weekly sales for each store and whatever department is available. And I have a certain thing which are called markdowns for each week, which although I haven't been able to figure out what they mean.

Irrespective, after a comprehensive exploratory data analysis, I have come to the conclusion that:

1. Type A stores are larger in size than Type B stores which are larger in size than Type B stores. And Type A stores have higher average sales over the period of 3 years worth of data that I have
2. The weekly markdown data that I have aren't affecting the sales
3. The month of December records the highest sales
4. During the holiday weeks, the sales increase

So basically I need to have a model which works on one or all of the above mentioned factors. But I am not able to figure out which model should I be going with. Would be great if anybody could at least just give me a certain direction.

Thanks.